# Numpy create four other points arrays based on one point array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy

Suppose I have an array `a` representing 3 center points of 3 rectangles. I want to create four other copied points based on each of points in array `a` by add `1` or minus `1` in x, y coordinates like shown in the picture.

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>>a
>>>out:[[ 0  1  2]
        [ 3  4  5]
        [ 6  7  8]]
```

I'm very new to numpy. What I can think of is that I can make 4 coupies of `a`, for the **first** do `a[:,0]+=1`, then `a[:,1]+=1`. for the **second** do `a[:,0]+=1`,then `a[:,1]-=1`.for the **third** do `a[:,0]-=1` then `a[:,1]+=1`, for the **fourth** do `a[:,0]-=1`then `a[:,1]-=1`. But I know it's stupid. So I 'm wondering if there is a clearer way to do it in numpy?
My expected outputs:

```
array_1 = [[ 1  2  2]
           [ 4  5  5]
           [ 7  8  8]]
array_2 = [[ 1  0  2]
           [ 4  3  5]
           [ 7  6  8]]
array_3 = [[ -1  2  2]
            [ 2  5  5]
            [ 5  8  8]]
array_4 = [[ -1  0  2]
            [ 2  3  5]
            [ 5  6  8]]
```

[image: create four other copy points based on center point]

Comment: Can you provide the expected output(s) for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a 3D array:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

b = np.array([[ 1, 1,0],
              [ 1,-1,0],
              [-1, 1,0],
              [-1,-1,0]])

# or programmatically
from itertools import product 
b = np.array(list(product([1,-1], [1,-1], [0])))


out = np.tile(a, (4,1,1))+b[:,None,:]

array([[[ 1,  2,  2],
        [ 4,  5,  5],
        [ 7,  8,  8]],

       [[ 1,  0,  2],
        [ 4,  3,  5],
        [ 7,  6,  8]],

       [[-1,  2,  2],
        [ 2,  5,  5],
        [ 5,  8,  8]],

       [[-1,  0,  2],
        [ 2,  3,  5],
        [ 5,  6,  8]]])
```

Subsetting:

```
out[0]

array([[1, 2, 2],
       [4, 5, 5],
       [7, 8, 8]])
```

Comment: Hi! May I ask you what could I do if I want to extract the `out[0][0]`, `out[1][0]`, `out[2][0]`,  `out[3][0]` as one array, then `out[0][1]`, `out[1][1]`, `out[2][1]`,  `out[3][1]` as second array, etc. Namely a list of array has length `3`, but  `4` points in each.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that what you need is to loop over a Cartesian product, there are many ways of doing so, one is to use itertools, here goes:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

list_of_arrays = []
for seq in itertools.product([1, -1], repeat=2):
    b = a.copy() 
    b[:,0]+=seq[0]
    b[:,1]+=seq[1]
    list_of_arrays.append(b)
```

list_of_arrays:

[array([[1, 2, 2],
[4, 5, 5],
[7, 8, 8]]),
array([[1, 0, 2],
[4, 3, 5],
[7, 6, 8]]),
array([[-1,  2,  2],
[ 2,  5,  5],
[ 5,  8,  8]]),
array([[-1,  0,  2],
[ 2,  3,  5],
[ 5,  6,  8]])]

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy broadcasting and itertools to generate the shifts:

```python
import itertools
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

shifts = np.array([(dx, dy, 0) for dx, dy in itertools.product([1, -1], repeat=2)])
shifted_a = a + shifts[:, None]
```

Comment: May I ask if I don't want `[1,-1]`, but` 2` or` -2` in x direction(the first column), `1` or `-1` in y direction(the second column), should the code be `shifts = np.array([(dx, dy, 0) for dx, dy in itertools.product([2, -1], repeat=2)])` ? (I think I write it wrong)

Comment: mozway's approach to generate that array is cleaner: `shifts = np.array(list(itertools.product([2,-2], [1,-1], [0])))`. The `repeat` argument tells `product()` to repeat the existing iterables (e.g. `product(A, B, repeat=3)` is the same as `product(A, B, A, B, A, B)`).